# Changing distance after some time on OnGUI Unity

Tags: unity

Though I am using IEnumerator to calculate the distance travelled value, the distance is updated very frequently, how can I change that? and why exactly increasing the time in WaitForSeconds function not changing the behaviour?

```
    void OnGUI ()
    {
        GUI.contentColor = Color.black;
        GUI.Label (new Rect (40, 40, 140, 40), "Speed : " + _speed, "color");
        StartCoroutine (distancetravelled ());
        GUI.Label (new Rect (40, 100, 100, 140), "Dist : " + Mathf.RoundToInt (distance * 1000) + " Kms", "color");

    }

    IEnumerator distancetravelled ()
    {
        timeInHours = (Time.smoothDeltaTime / 60) / 60;
        if(PlayerControl.collision != true)
        distance += _speed * timeInHours;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (60);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coroutine is being started multiple times. The coroutine will continue to wait in the background, even though you're starting new coroutines on top of it. If you only want to start the coroutine once, add a simple flag:

```
bool coroutineRunning = false;

void OnGUI ()
    {
        GUI.contentColor = Color.black;
        GUI.Label (new Rect (40, 40, 140, 40), "Speed : " + _speed, "color");
        if(!coroutineRunning)
            StartCoroutine (distancetravelled ());
        GUI.Label (new Rect (40, 100, 100, 140), "Dist : " + Mathf.RoundToInt (distance * 1000) + " Kms", "color");
    }

IEnumerator distancetravelled ()
    {
        timeInHours = (Time.smoothDeltaTime / 60) / 60;
        if(PlayerControl.collision != true)
        distance += _speed * timeInHours;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (60);
        coroutineRunning = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html) : This means that your OnGUI implementation might be called **several times per frame (one call per event)**. For more information on GUI events see the Event reference.